# Visualizing $Fct(Op_X, Set)$

Tags: category-theory, visualization

I can't seem to wrap my mind around what is going on when I try to visualize $Fct(Op_X, Set)$, as one example.  Now I know that a functor is a morphism between categories hence we have a morphism between the category of open sets of $X$ and the category of sets.

What does this mean, intuitively speaking what is really going on here and can anyone help me (and others that are finding some of this category theory quite abstract), visualize this?

Edit:  The image below is my ideas of what is going on.  Note, ()'s are open sets, |'s are for closed sets.  I don't know if denoting the functor as $F^{op}$, but what I imagine is that since U is an "inclusion" in V as $U \subset V$, that there are morphisims $r$ which map elements in $U$ to those same elements in $V$ - so as to get an inclusion i.e. it is these morphisms that create the inclusion.  The like idea is the same with $F(V) \rightarrow F(U)$ as although $F(U) \subset F(V)$, we are dealing with the opposite category open sets of $X$.   Please let me know if anything in the diagram is wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29#Presheaves (or do you really mean $\mathrm{Op}_X$ and not $\mathrm{Op}_X^{op}$?)

Comment: Thanks Martin, yes, I am working my way towards Presheaves and I know that I am just supposed to reverse the arrows as far as $Op_X$ is concerned.  As far as I can see, the category of open sets on X ($Op_X$) may have some morphisms between the open sets $U,V \subset X$  Whatever those morphisms are, we map those morphisms to some relationship between sets, say $A,B \in Set$.  I don't even know if I am correct in my thinking, but even if I am, what does this mean or do for me?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, I assume you're working on presheaves and so you're interesting in functors ${\mathcal O_X}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ rather than ${\mathcal O_X} \to \mathbf{Set}$ ($\mathcal O_X$ being the category of open sets of $X$).

First, just recall that $\mathcal O_X$ is the category with objects the open sets $U$ of the topological space $X$, and with morphisms the inclusions of open sets : it means that considering $U,V$ open sets of $X$, 
$$ \mathrm{Hom}(U,V) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} \{ \ast \} \quad &\text{if $U \subseteq V$} \\ \emptyset \quad &\text{otherwise.} \end{aligned} \right. $$

So a presheaf $F \colon {\mathcal O_X}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is the data of a set $F(U)$ forevery open set $U$ of $X$, and of a set function $F(V) \to F(U)$ for every inclusion $U \subseteq V$ of open sets in $X$. This data is required to satisfy : for open sets $U \subseteq V \subseteq W$ of $X$, the composite set function $F(W) \to F(V) \to F(U)$ is the function $F(W) \to F(U)$, and the function $F(U) \to F(U)$ coming from the trivial inclusion $U \subseteq U$ need to be the identity function.

*With the hands*, a presheaf is a set that evolves *continuously* along the topological space $X$. Especially, that set is compatible with *zooming in* the space $X$.

---

Mostly, nice visual examples of presheaves are sheaves (or at least separated presheaves). The most popular example is certainly the following : take a topological space $X$ (a topological variety is nice for visualisation), then the functor $U \mapsto \mathcal C(U,\mathbb R)$ of the continuous maps from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ is a presheaf (and even a sheaf) ; the set function $\mathcal C(V, \mathbb R) \to \mathcal C(U, \mathbb R)$ is just the restriction of the continuous maps defined on $V$ to $U \subseteq V$.

An other example : take again a topological variety $X$, the functor $U \mapsto \mathcal C_b(X, \mathbb R)$ of **bounded** continuous maps from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ is again a presheaf (actually a separated one).

Comment: "The most popular example is certainly the following:" How do you know that? And what is a topological variety?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Well, the sheaf on continuous functions on a (topological or differential) variety is often used in textbooks to introduce sheaves and presheaves. As for a topological variety, a compact way to say it is to defined it as a $\mathcal C^0$-differential variety : that is a separated topological space with a countable basis of open sets, admitting a open covering $(U_i)_i$ with $U_i$ homeomorphic to an open set of $\mathbb R^n$ for all $i$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Maybe I should have used 'manifold' instead of 'variety' ? If so, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Thanks Pece, I have a long way to go on this.. First, in your answer (and I have heard before), "with morphisms the inclusions of open sets".  Now to start with, the Functor F (Presheaf) maps the category of open sets to Sets.  So if we have an open set $U, V \in Op_x$ and after mapping this to another category (Set) in which $F(U), F(V) \in Set$ This "inclusion", how is it a morphism?  I mean if $U \subset V$, then $U$ is included in $V$ hence would be an "inclusion".  Wiki says a morphism is a structure preserving mapping, I don't see how morphisms are inclusions. Continued..

Comment: since morphisms are structure preserving maps, we would have that structure preserving maps are included in open sets.  I suppose that I am not very well versed at maps being in open sets.  I can see maps from one set to another as we would have one element in one set being mapped to another element in another set.  The best I can imagine is that we have arrows from one open set U to another open set V, then these arrows are operated on by the functor F which in preserving arrows would map $F(U) \rightarrow F(V)$.  I suppose then $Op_{X}^{op} \rightarrow Set$ gives $F(V) \rightarrow F(U)$ ...

Comment: and it is coming along (my reasoning), as I just reasoned out the above.  I can see that we get mappings from a larger open set to a smaller open set ($F(V) \rightarrow F(U)$) in Set.  So now would $F(U)$ house all of the information of $F(V)$?  If we kept doing this, would we get something that looked a bit like a funnel (if the sets were horizontal circles and the circle radius is according to the set size)?  This then I think is the idea of a stalk?  The end of the stalk (exit/lower part of funnel) is the smallest set one could possibly have with particular qualities)?  Thanks.

Comment: @Relative0 You are clearly still struggling with the very notion of category. You have to go back to the basics before going on with presheaves and sheaves. Morphisms do not preserve scratch (a priori) ! A category is just the data of some *objects* and *arrows* between them with a correct defined composition : *objects* do not have to be set, they could be numbers, points, or potatoes for that matter ; a fortiori *arrows* do not have to be concrete maps between sets. That the point of categories ! Without it, it will just be a fancy way to vacuously talk. (To be continued…)

Comment: […] In the case of presheaves, you actually can make sense of the categories at stake with sets as object and map as morphism, but that is not a smart way of thinking it. So my advice would be for you to take a little more time familiarising yourself with category language.